# Enabling "grace mode" for spring cache (returning old result while calculating new result asyncronously)

Tags: spring, caching, ehcache, spring-cache, caffeine

We would like to define our caches in our (spring boot) application similar to the concept varnish is doing with it's "grace mode". Right now we are using spring's `@Cacheable` annotation together with EhCache (but we are not bound to EhCache, if there's another cache backend able to to this would be fine, too).

Ideally I am searching for something like:

```java
@Cacheable(cacheNames = "name", evictionAfter = "5 minutes", graceTimeAfterEviction = "1 minute")
public myCachedMethod() { ... }
```

What I mean is: If a value in the cache is already evicted (in this example 5+ minutes old) and a new request is asking for it, I want to return the already evicted value (to this request and all following until the new value is stored -- or the grace time passed, too), but still run the method asynchronously filling the cache with a new value.

Most of the approaches I have seen so far solve this by refreshing the cache programmatically with an asynchronous, scheduled task. But that's not what I want, as my cache entries depend on the arguments, and I don't want to keep old values if no one asks for them any more.

Of course, I know that this is not possible in this way, as spring is not aware of the cache management itself. And it can't be configured in the cache backend neither, because the cache backend has no idea of how to refresh the cache.

But maybe there is an approach out there, I did not find (I searched a lot for it already for a few years/months).

According to the documentation of caffeine cache this seems to be supported (https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine, "https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine"), but the documentation is, again, only about scheduled refreshes, no grace period. And it does not work with spring's annoations.

There is a similar question here: [Spring cacheable asynchronous update while returns old cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62992349/spring-cacheable-asynchronous-update-while-returns-old-cache), but more focussed on the sync=true feature.

Comment: Caffeine’s refresh isn’t a scheduled task. It is performed for an entry when accessed and is eligible for refresh, making it dependent on the key. A refresh means it may be a stale value but usable, while an expired value is unusable. In your example it would be refreashAfterWrite=5min, expireAfterWrite=6min. If not accessed then the entry will be discarded and block, so refresh is a latency hiding technique. I don’t believe Spring Cache works well with this because it doesn’t provide the loader to the cache, so you’ll have to use the apis directly.

Comment: Thank you @BenManes, that sounds promising!
I will try this way... either with plain caffeine API or somehow creating own cache configuration/manager classes with spring.

Comment: This is supposedly the Spring [workaround](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/issues/311#issuecomment-478552898) which I think uses a custom provider (see [coffee-boots/issues/11](https://github.com/stepio/coffee-boots/issues/11)). In my work code we don't use Spring (Guice) and there we use the apis directly.